# Can we mute remote audio at source while using Agora Web SDK API?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am working on an application where host needs to mute other participants. I have tried using `remotestream.muteAudio()` api. But this doesn't mute the audio at source. Which means with this API, if host mutes Participant A it is muted only for the host. But participant B can still hear Participant A.

I went through the API documentation and couldn't find the solution.
https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#muteaudio

Can this be achieved by any ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi there you need to use the [Agora RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/product_rtm?platform=All%20Platforms) to do that.

You can [create an RTM channel](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmclient.html#createchannel) with the same name as the RTC channel. Alternatively, You can use P2P messaging(Also present in RTM) if that suits your use case better.

Then the host can send a message to the concerned user to mute. On receiving this message, the user can call the `muteAudio` on their side, thereby muting the audio at source. All of this would be done programmatically.

Comment: Is not there any way to mute streamer voice on clients screen?